# wamp with two php versions older version not working

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I just installed WAMP with two versions of PHP 5.3.13 and PHP 5.2.2

PHP 5.3.13 works find but in the WAMP controller if I switch PHP version my localhost does not work. I even re-started WAMP and checked the Apache error logs and saw this error:

```
[Thu Jul 11 15:22:22 2013] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Thu Jul 11 15:22:22 2013] [notice] Child 5676: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Thu Jul 11 15:22:23 2013] [notice] Child 5676: Released the start mutex
[Thu Jul 11 15:22:24 2013] [notice] Child 5676: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Jul 11 15:22:24 2013] [notice] Child 5676: Child process is exiting
[Thu Jul 11 15:22:24 2013] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
```

What Does this mean? And what do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: That log is just showing the initiated shut down event - not an error.

Comment: Try starting apache (httpd) through the command line instead of through WAMP, you are more likely to get a useful error this way.

Comment: how do I start wamp via cmd?

Comment: I ran `NET Start wampapache` in cmd and wampapache service could not be started. :(

Comment: Try locating Apache installation directory. Then look for Apache>>Bin>>httpd.exe Run this file from command prompt and see if you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with particular PHP release. So, you can try few things.

- Check if required version of Microsoft Visual C++ is installed. In case of PHP 5.2.x, I guess the required one is VC6 (x86)
- Check if you are using correct version of Apache Handler. Apache Handler are different for each release of PHP and shouldn't be used of different release..
- Try running Apache httpd.exe from the command prompt to see if you get an error.